# Generate a thumbnail image every X seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to generate a thumbnail every minute, but i'm getting the following error:

```
ffmpeg -i Hung.mp4 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg

[mjpeg @ 0x2f06da0] bitrate tolerance too small for bitrate
[mjpeg @ 0x2f1b7c0] ff_frame_thread_encoder_init failed
Output #0, image2, to 'img%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 1280x536 [SAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 0.02 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-07-22 00:01:41
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mjpeg)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Comment: You need to include the complete ffmpeg console output and not just a segment.

Comment: it's the complete output!

Comment: Where is the version and configuration information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [bitrate tolerence](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Codec-Options) using `-bt`. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i Hung.mp4 -f image2 -bt 20M -vf fps=fps=10/60 img%03d.jpg
```

There's a relevant discussion [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/+bug/320720) and a bug report [here](http://roundup.libav.org/issue1376).

Comment: it generated 4 images for 2:31 min video... ffmpeg -i Hung.mp4 -f image2 -bt 20M -vf fps=fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg insted of 1 per 60 seconds